# Merge pandas multiindex column that has same value

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on python for document extraction and it seems that I run into a problem.

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4O5B.png)

After converting the pandas dataframe to HTML, I notice there is a multiindex column on the dataframe[multiindex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnI4w.png).

I want to merge the "Name", "Measurement Point" and "Test Item" while still keeping the "Criterion" the same

I have tried to merge it using

```
df.columns.map('|'.join).str.strip('|')
```

but it doesn't remove the duplicate value.

I want to make it like this [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck1Dz.png) but instead I'm getting [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2HBP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `f-strings`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Name','Name'),
                                 ('Measurement Point','Measurement Point'),
                                 ('Test Item','Test Item'),
                                 ('Criterion','Min')])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns=mux)
print(df)
  Name Measurement Point Test Item Criterion
  Name Measurement Point Test Item       Min
0  NaN               NaN       NaN       NaN

df.columns = [f'{a}|{b}' if a!=b else a for a, b in df.columns]

print(df)
  Name Measurement Point Test Item Criterion|Min
0  NaN               NaN       NaN           NaN
```

EDIT: If need combination MultiIndex and Index it is not possible.

You can replace if same values in both levels to empty strings:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Name','Name'),
                                 ('Measurement Point','Measurement Point'),
                                 ('Test Item','Test Item'),
                                 ('Criterion','Min')])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns=mux)
print(df)
  Name Measurement Point Test Item Criterion
  Name Measurement Point Test Item       Min
0  NaN               NaN       NaN       NaN
```

---

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(a,b) if a!=b else (a,'') for a, b in df.columns])

#seems looks OK   
print(df)
  Name Measurement Point Test Item Criterion
                                         Min
0  NaN               NaN       NaN       NaN

#real MultiIndex values
print(df.columns)
MultiIndex([(             'Name',    ''),
            ('Measurement Point',    ''),
            (        'Test Item',    ''),
            (        'Criterion', 'Min')],
           )
```

Another idea is manually set columns names to MultiIndex by `set_index`:

```
df = df.set_index([('Name','Name'),
                   ('Measurement Point','Measurement Point'),
                  ('Test Item','Test Item')])

df.index.names = [list(x)[0] for x in df.index.names]

print(df)
                                 Criterion
                                       Min
Name Measurement Point Test Item          
NaN  NaN               NaN             NaN
```

---

```
print(df.columns)
MultiIndex([('Criterion', 'Min')],
           )
             
print(df.index)
MultiIndex([(nan, nan, nan)],
           names=['Name', 'Measurement Point', 'Test Item'])
```

Comment: This is helpful for me. however, is it possible to keep "Criterion" stay as multilevel instead of being merged become "Criterion|Min"?

Comment: @ValStash - You need part of columns like Multiindex and part like Index ? It is not possible.

Comment: @ValStash - Added part EDIT to my answer.

Comment: Oh okay, I will use your second solution to replace the same value with empty string, thanks